# How to place two root component in index.html?

Tags: angular

I try to place two components in compiled index.html:

```
<app-block></app-block>
<app-block></app-block>
```

But but default it should be in app-root:

```
<app-root>
    <app-block></app-block>
    <app-block></app-block>
</app-root>
```

So, I dont want to use `<app-root>`, just want show the same components independent.

I have tried to modify root module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [BlockComponent, BlockComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But as result I get only one component on the page:

```
block works!
```

How to use it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't put anything inside the `index.html` since this isn't the purpose of this file. `<app-root>` is pointing to your `app-routing.module.ts` file and isn't meant to contain any code.

so let `index.html` be

```html
<app-root></app-root>
```

and within your `app.component.html` file, put the component you wanted to have twice. like the following

```html
  <app-block></app-block>
  <app-block></app-block>
```

dont forget to add your component module -> `AppBlockModule` inside your `app.module.ts` file.